# New value for cookie appended

Tags: javascript, cookies

This javascript code

```
function writeCookie(CookieName, CookieValue, CookieDuration) {
    var expiration = new Date();
    var now = new Date();
    expiration.setTime(now.getTime() + (parseInt(CookieDuration) * 60000));
    document.cookie = CookieName + '=' + escape(CookieValue) + '; expires=' + expiration.toGMTString() +
        '; path=/';
}

function readCookie(CookieName) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        var beginning = document.cookie.indexOf(CookieName + "=");
        if (beginning != -1) {
            beginning = beginning + CookieName.length + 1;
            var ending = document.cookie.indexOf(";", beginning);
            if (ending == -1) ending = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(beginning, ending));
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
    return "";
}
var before = readCookie('totali');
var after = before + 1;
writeCookie('totali', after, 43200);
```

Should read cookie 'totali', add "1" to its value and then rewrite the new value.
The first time I run the code, cookie becomes "1", but the second time becomes "11", the third "111" and so on.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Try `var after = parseInt(before) + 1;`

Comment: Now the value of the cookie becomes "NaN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating strings. Convert the value read from the cookie into a number before attempting to add it:

```
var after = parseInt(before) + 1;
```

But the problem is that the first time you read the cookie, the value is an empty string, and `parseInt("")` will be `NaN`. In this case, you have to check before you use it. This will assign `1` if the function returns an empty string, or the value stored in the cookie + 1 if not:

```
var after = (before.trim() == "") ? 1 : parseInt(before) + 1;
```

This assumes you never place anything other than a number in that `totali` cookie.

See http://jsfiddle.net/9rLZP/3/ (I changed the name of the cookie, so you can see the change without having to remove the previous cookie)

Comment: Now the value of the cookie becomes "NaN" (even in the example you posted on jsfiddle)

Comment: Ok. The problem is that the function can return any type, number or not. The first time, it will return a "" and parseInt("") is NaN. What could be done is to check the return value and if string, replace with 0. I'll fix that in the fiddle and edit the answer.